# Why this mobile navigation toggle not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, toggle

I am trying to create a mobile navigation (toggle type) on a breaking point 768px.

My mark up is:

```
<div class="tm_menu_mobile">

    <div class="menu_icon">
        <div class="three_line"></div>
        <div class="three_line"></div>
        <div class="three_line"></div>
    </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div id="nav">
        <div class="navigasi_menu">
            <div class="navigasi_list">
                <div class="nav-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-7"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="#">Sample Page</a></li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-9"><a href="#">test page 1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

this mobile navigation should be hidden screens wide above 768px. So I put following java script code in to the header:

```
/* Mobile navigation*/  
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#nav').hide();
    $('.menu_icon').click(function() {
            $('#nav').slideToggle('fast');
            return false;
        });
});
```

and I put following CSS code into my style sheet:

```
/* Primary mobile menu */
 .tm_menu_mobile {
    display: block;
    margin: 15px auto !important;
    width: 98.5% !important;
    background:#0071B7;
    padding:6px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
/* avoiding horizontal scroll bar across the site */
 .navigasi_menu {
    width: 100%
}
.navigasi_menu li {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
/* Making navigation li one below another */
 .navigasi_menu li:hover {
    width: 100%
}
.tm_menu_mobile .menu_icon {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border:2px solid #000;
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.menu_icon .three_line {
    float:none;
    width:36px;
    height:5px;
    background:#fff;
    margin:9px auto;
}
.tm_menu_mobile #nav {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

but toggle not working.
Also when I hovering the navigation in 768px screen it's not stable... it's 3rd li comes above the 1st..

but the same js fiddle work [here the sample js toggle I tested](http://jsfiddle.net/riffaz/z4q9wsjc/)
and the site I am trying is bit different. [SITE](http://asiamediaglobal.net/riffaz/athavaneng-for-live-test/)

How can I get it work?
the issue is related to wordpress??

Comment: I can see in mobile view. You have an error on line 101 in your js script

Comment: do you run your code on your page as document ready callback?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña I've changed `$`to `Jquery` but still there is an issue.. buit I could not see the error as firebug shows in source file. now it says on line 92

Comment: @marcel my js script starts `jQuery(document).ready(function() { }` as you see on the question

Comment: Try binding the click to the document -- $(document).on("click","'.menu_icon'", function() {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
    /* Mobile navigation toggle*/   
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
        jQuery('.tm_menu_mobile #nav').hide();
        jQuery('.menu_icon').click(function() {
                jQuery('.tm_menu_mobile #nav').slideToggle('fast');
                return false;
            });
    });                 
</script>
```